# R: correcting residuals

Tags: r, svm, random-forest, cross-validation, knn

I am trying to correct residuals in the Carseats data set provided in R. I am to start with a random forest, and correct these residuals with a support vector machine with lamda=0.1, then correct those residuals using KNN with lamda=0.1. At each step I am to use 5-fold CV to tune the parameters mtry (3,5,10) for random forest, gamma (0.01,.1,1,10) in svm, and k (1,5,10,20) in KNN. I am very new to this, and I have attempted the problem, but I honestly have no idea if I did any of this right. Here is what I have:

```
set.seed (1)

##Random forest
#mtry=3
rf3 <- randomForest(Sales ~ ., 
 data = Carseats, mtry = 3, ntree = 500,
  importance = TRUE)

#mtry=5
rf5 <- randomForest(Sales ~ ., 
 data = Carseats, mtry = 5, ntree = 500,
  importance = TRUE)

#mtry=10
rf10 <- randomForest(Sales ~ ., 
 data = Carseats, mtry = 10, ntree = 500,
  importance = TRUE)

#cross validation to pick best mtry -- am getting an error
library(tree)
cv.carseats = rfcv(trainx=Carseats[,-11], trainy=Carseats[,-11],cv.fold=5)
cv.carseats

##SVM
library(e1071)
f = svm(Sales~.,data=Carseats)

#gamma = 0.01
svm(Sales~., data=Carseats, type = NULL, kernel = "polynomial", degree = 3,
gamma = if (is.vector(x)) .01 
else 1 / ncol(x),
coef0 = 0, cost = 1)

#gamma = 0.1
svm(Sales~., data=Carseats, type = NULL, kernel = "polynomial", degree = 3,
gamma = if (is.vector(x)) 0.1 
else 1 / ncol(x),
coef0 = 0, cost = 1)

#gamma = 1
svm(Sales~., data=Carseats, type = NULL, kernel = "polynomial", degree = 3,
gamma = if (is.vector(x)) 1 
else 1 / ncol(x),
coef0 = 0, cost = 1)

#gamma = 10
svm(Sales~., data=Carseats, type = NULL, kernel = "polynomial", degree = 3,
gamma = if (is.vector(x)) 10 
else 1 / ncol(x),
coef0 = 0, cost = 1)

#cross validation to pick best gamma
tune.out=tune(svm,Sales~.,data=Carseats,kernel ="polynomial",
ranges =list(cost=c(0.01,0.1,1,10)))
```

Any feedback is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, this probably belongs on cross-validated rather than stack overflow since your problem seems to be experimental design rather than coding difficulty.

Second, if you are going to be doing machine learning using many different models, I would recommend you check out [`caret`](http://topepo.github.io/caret/index.html).  They have a lot of infrastructure built in for training and testing models with different architectures of cross-validation and many other parameter options, so you can save yourself plenty of time in experimental design there.  This will probably solve most of the issues you are having.

Third, I don't know what you are talking about when you say you are using "lamda=0.1" for you SVM and KNN models.  Neither of these models have `lambda` as a parameter, so I am not sure what you are doing.  It is possible this is just something I am not familiar with, but if so, it is probably unusual enough to justify an explanation or a link to one.

Finally, while it is not too uncommon to use one model to model the residuals of another model, continuing to model residuals with a third model is getting a little machine learning Inception-ie.  You are almost certainly going to start over-fitting your data.  If you are not happy with your results from the first random forest model, I would suggest that rather than trying to fit residuals, you try a [Boosted Decision Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_boosting) instead such as [Adaboost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdaBoost) (note: boosting can be done with other models as well, decision trees are just the most common).  These models function like decision trees, but as more trees are built, they sample more strongly from the samples mis-classified by other trees, generally building a stronger classifier by focusing on the difficult samples.  Because of this, they are prone to over-fitting as well, but most implementations will include tools to help avoid this.

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of cross-validated.